# Which one of the following sentences is correct? (scrambled text question)

Tags: descriptive-grammar

Which one of the following sentences is correct?

a. I drive to german used an old blue car.

b. I drive an used  old blue car to german.

c. I used an old blue car drive to german.

My English teacher says the correct answer is (a) but I think (b) is more correct and grammatically make sense.

Comment: None off them are correct.

Comment: "I used to drive an old blue german car" is right answer.

Comment: They are all complete gibberish and make no grammatical sense.

Comment: Among other things, "German" (and "Germany") should be capitalized.

Comment: This site is not really for solving jumbles, scrambles, crosswords, etc. It's for capturing expert level answers to questions about English words, pronunciation, spelling, grammar, history, regional differences, etc. On the other hand, we welcome all kinds of English related social fun at our chat site, [chat]. Please join us there!

Answer (score 1):

"I used to drive an old blue german car" is right answer.
"German" is an adjective it can't be used as it has been used in all the options.

Answer (score 0):

**None** of these choices is correct.  "**To German**" is wrong-- did you mean "*to Germany*"?

You would need to make the following changes to the sentences for any of them to be correct.

```
Wrong: a.  I drive to german used an old blue car.
OK:    a2. I drive to Germany an old, blue used car.

Wrong: b.  I drive an used old blue car to german.
OK:    b2. I drive a used old blue car to Germany.
Best:  b3. I drive an old blue used car to Germany.

Wrong: c.  I used an old blue car drive to german.
Right: c2. I used an old blue car to drive to Germany.

Also Right:  c3.  I used to drive an old blue car to Germany.
```

Choice b2 is fine, but choice b3 sounds better because "used car" is such a common phrase (almost like a 'compound noun').  This makes it sound more natural.

In choice c and c2, the meaning of the word "used" is different.  It was changed from an adjective (meaning 'pre-owned') to a verb (meaning 'employed' or 'utilized').

Choice c3 changes the meaning of "used" another way. Here, "used to" signifies an Imperfect past tense (repeated actions in the past tense), like "I used to go to kindergarten".

Comment: I would add that a2, although grammatical, is a bit odd and probably wouldn't occur in speech or prose writing. It might occur in poetry in order to fit a meter or rhyme.